# Am I supposed to use generating functions or combinatorics or something for this question?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

If there are 201 seats in the Parliamentary chamber, how many different ways are there for the numbers
of seats to be allocated amongst three political parties, subject to no one party having an overall
majority?

I could figure it out manually. 201/3 = 67 per party. Thats one way. Then divide 67/2 (because you can move 2 from one party at a time to ensure the other 2 are equal) = 33.5 but use lower bound as a person cannot be split in half. That makes it 100+100+1 = 201. So now thats 33 ways. But party that gives up 2 each time can change. i.e. Party A gives up 2 members to B&C until 1 remain. Then party B gives up... then C. So would it be 1+(33*3) = 100 ways?

Is there a cleaner way to do this, say using generating funtions or combinatorics of some sort? If not I dont know why the would ask this question.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method one: a solution by manual inspection

First, note that no party can have more than $100$ seats otherwise they have an overall majority.

Let's call the parties $A$, $B$ and $C$ and look at the possible seats for $B$ and $C$ as we change the number of seats won by $A$.

- If $A$ has $0$ seats, then either $B$ or $C$ must have at least $101$
  seats, so this is not possible.
- If $A$ has $1$ seat, then the remaining $200$ seats must be split $100$
  each to $B$ and $C$. $1$ way.
- If $A$ has $2$ seats, then the remaining $199$ seats can be split $(99,100)$ or $(100,99)$. $2$ ways.
- If $A$ has $3$ seats, then $198$ seats can be split $(98,100)$, $(99,99)$ or $(100,98)$. $3$ ways.
- If $A$ has $4$ seats, then $197$ seats can be split $(97,100)$, $(98,99)$, $(98,99)$ or $(100,97)$. $4$ ways.

Hopefully this is enough to establish the pattern which continues up to $A$ having $100$ seats and leads to the solution.

---

### Method two: a solution by combinatorics

This can be solved using the stars and bars method and using inclusion-exclusion to eliminate combinations where one party has a majority.

The total number of ways to allocate the seats is$$\binom{201+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{203}{2}$$
but if we force the first group to have at least $101$ seats we can use$$\binom{203-101}{2}=\binom{102}{2}$$ to get the number of combinations where party $A$ has at least $101$ seats. As there are three parties we need to multiply this by $3$ when we exclude these combinations. The overall number of ways to allocate the seats is$$\binom{203}{2}-3\binom{102}{2}=5050$$

Comment: I suppose you are right as Ive recieved 2 different methods with the same answer. Thanks. However, you say : `If A has 2 seats, then the remaining 199 seats can be split (99,100) or (100,99). 2 ways` . But wouldnt having a party with 100 seats, and the rest have 99 & 2 give the party an overall majority, violating the question? Or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the term 'overall majority'. $99+2>100$ so the two smaller parties together can outvote the largest party. In general, one party needs to have more than half the seats to have an overall majority.

Answer (score 0):

We seek the number of integer solutions to the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3=201\tag{1}
$$
where $ 0\leq x _i \leq 100$. You can solve this using generating functions by noting that this is equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{201}$ in the generating function of 
$$
(1+x+\dotsb x^{100})^3
=\frac{(1-x^{101})^3}{(1-x)^3}
=(1-3x^{101}+3x^{202}+x^{303})\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}\right).\tag{2}
$$
Use the identity 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^n.\tag{3}
$$
(which can be obtained by repeatedly differentiating the geometric series) to find that the coefficient of $x^{201}$ is 
$$
\binom{201+2}{2}-3\binom{(201-101)+2}{2}\tag{4}
$$
which can be obtained equivalently using inclusion exclusion.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Something that I have confusion with other questions of the same answer method: how did you get `-3(C((201-101)+2,2)`, specifically the -3 part. how did you use inclusion exclusion to determine it must be -3?

Comment: @ Alonzo Robbe I didn't use inclusion exclusion, although inclusion exclusion gives the same answer. I used generating functions. In equation (2) when we multiply out the series we look for what contributes to the $x^{201}$ term in the product. By inspection it is $1\times\binom{201+2}{2}x^{201}+(-3x^{101}\times\binom{102}{2}x^{100})$